# What command deletes a row (apache poi)?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use `xlsx` . I need to delete a row . Let's say row 5 . It means that row 6 should become 5 , 7 should become 6 ...

I tried

```
sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(6));
 sheet.shiftRows(6, 6, -1);
```

But the above commands remove values only . and leave blank cells . But I need to simulate `delete` option in excel .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try below code :

```
public static void removeRow(HSSFSheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
    int lastRowNum=sheet.getLastRowNum();
    if(rowIndex>=0&&rowIndex<lastRowNum){
        sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex+1,lastRowNum, -1);
    }
    if(rowIndex==lastRowNum){
        HSSFRow removingRow=sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if(removingRow!=null){
            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
        }
    }
}
```

It will shift the row and then delete it.